# Training with optuna-tuned hyperparameters leads to different results

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, hyperparameter-tuning

I'm training an image classifier in Pytorch Lightning and tuning hyperparameters with Optuna. When I use the best hyperparameters to train a separate model, the accuracies differ from those obtained in the optuna experiment. The train/val/test sets are all the same and I've set random seeds as well. Can anyone suggest a way I can repeat the accuracy scores from the optuna experiment?

Comment: Can you please post the model scores for comparison between Optuna and your Pytorch model using the same settings?